# Retrofit with multipart image parameters

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit, multipartform-data

I am working with Retrofit Library 1.9.0 version for Multipart upload.I am using following code to send multipart data using Retrofit Library.Here Everything works fine but image is not reflecting into database.Same thing i tried from postman plugin there it is working fine.

```
public static void userRegistration(Activity activity, String firstName, String lastName, String fatherName, String email, String mobile, String profileName, String password, String confirmPassowrd, String gender, String countryId, String userId, String realpath) {
        apiInterface = (ApiInterface) activity;
        showDialog(activity);
        MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");
//        MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data");
        File file = null;
//        file = new File(uri.toString());
//        file = new File(uri.getPath());
        file = new File(realpath);
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, file);

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://example.com/rest_api/index.php/user").build();
        Api api = restAdapter.create(Api.class);
        api.RegistrationUser(userId, firstName, fatherName, lastName, email, profileName, password, confirmPassowrd, gender, mobile, countryId, requestBody, new Callback<Registration>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Registration registration, Response response) {
                mView.dismiss();
                apiInterface.requestCompleted(registration, "registration");
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                mView.dismiss();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });


    }
```

api method..

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/registration")
    void RegistrationUser(@Part("user_type_id") String uid, @Part("first_name")String fName, @Part("father_name")String father, @Part("last_name")String lName, @Part("email")String mail, @Part("username")String name, @Part("password")String psw, @Part("confirm_password")String cPsw, @Part("gender")String gender, @Part("mobile_number")String phone, @Part("country_id")String cId, @Part("user_image") RequestBody image, Callback<Registration> callback);
```

I thought something went wrong in my procedure.Please suggest me..

Comment: I am not sure but I think 1.9.0 have an issue with multipart. Please try out retrofit version 2.0

Comment: Thanks for the reply Viren,But my problem i have lot of calls with 1.9.0 version.It should be difficult for me to change all calls to 2.0.So i am trying in same version.

Comment: please add "user_image" + "\";filename=\"file.jpg\"" as key in your method(RegisterationUser)

Comment: I didn't get this.Can you please elaborate your comment..And the above method you mentioned is Retrofit API call..

Comment: I know man...jz try in this very manner.. @Part("user_image" + "\";filename=\"file.jpg\"") RequestBody image

Comment: It is giving Annotations are not allowed here..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117780/discussion-between-viren-and-malli).